# How to persist changes in datagrid after each change?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid, editing, persist

I have a DataGrid which is bound to an array of data objects. How do I persist changes (save updated values to the database) of the data each time any field is changed? What event should I use?

Comment: What do you mean by **"persist"** ... do you mean you want to maintain a log of changes? Or you want the changes to be updated back into the Array?

Comment: I want to save the updated values to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the DataGrid.CellEditEnding event and do whatever you need to save or validate your data.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.celleditending.aspx